# HashMap question: Algorithm that I am trying to figure out

Tags: java, algorithm

So I have some code that I want to learn about. I will demo a portion of it as I am just confused about one step to the hashmap. If I run the code below, and input a string such as ("ploploplp"), 'p' gets mapped to 91, l gets mapped to 61, and o gets mapped to 31. The only key value pair I get is o being mapped to 31. Shouldn't p and l get mapped to 32 and 33 respectively in this code? Any input would greatly help thanks.

```
public static void printDuplicateCharacters(String word){
    char[] characters = word.toCharArray();

    Map<Character, Integer> charMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (Character ch: characters){
        if (charMap.containsKey(ch)){
            charMap.put(ch,  charMap.get(ch) + 30);
        } else{
            charMap.put(ch, 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1 + 30 + 30 + 30 = 91, not 32.

Comment: And I should get mapped to 61. 1+30+30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
see "p" in your code,
1.first 'p' not contains , so call charMap.put(ch, 1); now in map 'p'->1 ,right?
2.second 'p' contains map , so call  charMap.put(ch,  charMap.get(ch) + 30); now in map 
'p'-> 31 , right?
3.third 'p' in map 'p'->61 , right?
4.fourth 'p' in map 'p'->91 , right?
```

Answer (score 0):

your code works like below

first occurrence will add 1
and further occurrence will add 30 to the value,

so in case of 'p' :

```
1 + 30 + 30 + 30 = 91
```

in case of 'o' :

```
1 + 30 = 31
```

Hope it helps